# How to send key combination to selenium chromedriver?

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js, selenium-chromedriver

i am using uirecorder to create mocha test cases to test my web program. I want to send some key combination like "Metakey + R". But i couldn't accomplish that.

here is an example of ui recorder generated step:

```
it('sendKeys: {DOWN}', async function(){
    await driver.sendKeys('{DOWN}');
});
```

this works perfectly. but i couldn't figure out how to send key combinations.
The question is how can i send key combinations like ctrl+a ( holding ctrl and pressing a then leaving ctrl)

**SOLUTION THAT I USE:**

i just did it like this, and works fine.

```
await driver.sendKeys('{CTRL}a{CTRL}');
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of actions class in selenium ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i just did it like this, and works fine.

```
await driver.sendKeys('{CTRL}a{CTRL}');
```

Comment: Solution provided by me was for python, I believe this is in node , well you solved your own problem ! cheers !

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActionSequence class to perform actions in selenium using Node.

For pressing `Left control + a` you can simulate mouse action like this :

```
new webdriver.ActionSequence(driver).keyDown(webdriver.Key.LEFT_CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(webdriver.Key.LEFT_CONTROL).perform();
```

More Reference :
[Reference 1](http://www.softpost.org/selenium-with-node-js/performing-advanced-actions-using-selenium-in-node-js/)

[Reference 2](https://gist.github.com/umaar/9051143)

Comment: ty for your answer. but i couldn't make it work in my test file. but i did it some other way. check my solution, please.

Answer (score 0):

Using Keys class:

```
String keypress = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a");
driver.findElement(By.locator("value of locator")).sendKeys(keypress);
```

Using Actions class:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);  
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who finds this in the future, here is a solution that worked for me:

```
const {Key} = require('selenium-webdriver');

...

await driver.actions()
  .keyDown(Key.SHIFT)
  .sendKeys(Key.TAB)
  .keyUp(Key.SHIFT)
  .perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
button.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND,Keys.RETURN)
```